# Changing variable identifier programmatically

Tags: android

I have a question about Android that I have been struggling with.
In my android project, there is a class called Tracks.java and within this class there are static int[]'s like this:

```
public class Tracks(){

static int[] Track1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
static int[] Track2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
.....
static int[] Track10 = {45, 46, 47, 48, 49}

}
```

In an other class called Race.java I need to use these int[]'s  dependent on the number of the track currently being used.

```
public class License extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        int TrackNO = 1;
        int checkpoint;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        checkpoint = Tracks.Track1[0]; //Now checkpoint == 1;

        }
```

If I now change the TrackNO to 2, then the int checkpoint should == 6.
How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: you need an array of array, i think

Comment: please consider to rename your variables according to the java naming conventions... variable names should start with a lowercase and use the camelcase notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your tracks in an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<int[]> trackList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

trackList.add(track1);
trackList.add(track2);
```

later

```
int[] track = trackList.get(1);
```

Comment: Thanks a'lot, this seems like a good approach. I'll try this later and check your answer as accepted if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Don't set the `checkpoint` variable in `onCreate`. Tracks are chaning during runtime, right? You should have a method called, for example, `changeTrack(int track)`:

```
public void changeTrack(int track) {
    switch(track) {
    case 1:
        checkpoint = Tracks.Track1[0];
        break;
    case 2:
        checkpoint = Tracks.Track2[0];
        break;
    ....
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could add all the `Track` arrays to another array/list, and access them from that list.

Comment: He has 10 tracks in his example. Using `switch`, you can also initialize everything specific for that track (Except for checkpoint). If you have 100 tracks, of course you should use another array/list...

Comment: yor gold badge should be removed fir that answer ;-)

Comment: What does it have to do with this answer?